# How to add Progress bar dialogue and Progress notification?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to add a progressbar and progress bar notification,for photo upload.How can I take the length of my file and how to update the progress bar based on how much bytes it transferred,I found many tutorials for simply adding progress bar and progress notification.But I need to update the progress bar correctly based on my file upload.For ex if the file size is 1 MB and if 512 kb is uploaded then I want to show my progress bar and notification bar as 50 percentage is upload. I am a beginner can anyone help me or any tutorials available for this ??

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: here is my code please check the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115961/how-to-set-progress-bar-and-progress-notification-bar-for-an-image-upload

Comment: Why are you opening multiple questions for the same problem ?

Comment: sorry for that,i did not get any anwer for the first question